# Disabling JMX in a spring application

Tags: java, spring, jmx

I'm trying to disable jmx so that i don't get:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'mbeanExporter'anymore.
```

I've found a partial answer saying that I should include this in the `application.properties` file:

- `spring.datasource.jmx-enabled=false`

So I created the file with that one line. But how do I make sure that Spring acutally reads it? Do I need to edit something in spring.xml? If so, where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using spring boot? If so you just need to place the file in src\main\resources\application.properties by default

You can check sample projects here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples

Comment: Yes, I'm using spring boot and I put the file under src\main\resources. Is that supposed to just fix it and disable JMX? Because in my case this doesn't happen.

Comment: That should be enough - your log should show that jmx isnt enabled. Another option to confirm it would be to disable the banner from application.properties as a test - spring.main.show_banner=false

Comment: If not, where am I supposed to use this property in my code to desable JMX for the entire application?

Comment: Sorry - I think the property you need to set it spring.jmx.enabled=false

Comment: Are you doing a clean build and install?

Comment: Clean build and instal, along with spring.jmx.enabled=false solved it, thank you! Well, at least it solved the JMX problem. Now I'm getting some hibernate JPA autoconfiguration problems, but to be fair that's besides the scope of this question.

Comment: No problem - check the samples project for examples

Comment: NB The samples have been renamed "smoke tests" (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/d5c0009c6eb0e77e4e1013d149d33de7dccdbd4d) and are now here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-tests/spring-boot-smoke-tests

Answer (score 41):

You need to disable the setting in your application.properties file (it is automatically turned on if not set). Either edit or create this file:
**src/main/resources/config/application.properties**

That is for a maven project, so if not in maven, just put 'resources' at the same level as your java folder.

You will just need this single line in the file (it can be blank otherwise):

```
spring.jmx.enabled=false
```

If you want to add other settings, here are all the options:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

Comment: Just in Case you come here like me wondering why you could not disable it during tests with ``spring.jmx.enabled=false``.Make sure you do not have the ``@EnableMBeanExport`` additionally on your application configuration. It seems to override/rule the Property.

Comment: Hello, can we set spring?JMX.enabled=true programmatically like we can set server port through the class same way can we set this property true?

Answer (score 25):

In my case, it was IntelliJ.

IntelliJ have a setting "Enable JMX agent" in the run configuration. This should be unchecked to disable JMX.

If checked, this will override any setting that you make in the application via properties/yml.

Comment: The same applies to Eclipse, I had the same problem and there was a checkbox in the Run configuration which was enabling JMX.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to disable jmx autoconfiguration:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={JmxAutoConfiguration.class})
```