# Tomcat and Tomcat dbcp issue after upgrade to v9.0.58

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I'm getting this issue when upgrading Tomcat and Tomcat DBCP from v9.0.54 to v.9.0.58 with Java 11.

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-02-08T08:24:15,900Z ERROR [tartedMain] SpringApplication [SpringApplication.java:854] Application run failed
org.springframework.jmx.export.UnableToRegisterMBeanException: Unable to register MBean [org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource@3b60547f] with key 'datasource'; nested exception is javax.management.NotCompliantMBeanException: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceMXBean: Method org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DataSourceMXBean.getSoftMinEvictableIdleDuration has parameter or return type that cannot be translated into an open type
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanNameOrInstance(MBeanExporter.java:626)
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.lambda$registerBeans$2(MBeanExporter.java:552)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1336)
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeans(MBeanExporter.java:552)
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.afterSingletonsInstantiated(MBeanExporter.java:435)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:972)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:765)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:445)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343)
    at com.wk.gbs.intakeportal.IntakePortalWarApplication.main(IntakePortalWarApplication.java:30)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: javax.management.NotCompliantMBeanException: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceMXBean: Method org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DataSourceMXBean.getSoftMinEvictableIdleDuration has parameter or return type that cannot be translated into an open type
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Introspector.throwException(Introspector.java:467)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanAnalyzer.<init>(MBeanAnalyzer.java:120)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanAnalyzer.analyzer(MBeanAnalyzer.java:102)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MXBeanIntrospector.getAnalyzer(MXBeanIntrospector.java:74)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanIntrospector.getPerInterface(MBeanIntrospector.java:192)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanSupport.<init>(MBeanSupport.java:138)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MXBeanSupport.<init>(MXBeanSupport.java:66)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Introspector.makeDynamicMBean(Introspector.java:203)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerObject(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:888)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:320)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:522)
    at org.springframework.jmx.support.MBeanRegistrationSupport.doRegister(MBeanRegistrationSupport.java:138)
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanInstance(MBeanExporter.java:672)
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanNameOrInstance(MBeanExporter.java:616)
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Method org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DataSourceMXBean.getSoftMinEvictableIdleDuration has parameter or return type that cannot be translated into an open type
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.ConvertingMethod.from(ConvertingMethod.java:46)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MXBeanIntrospector.mFrom(MXBeanIntrospector.java:84)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MXBeanIntrospector.mFrom(MXBeanIntrospector.java:54)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanAnalyzer.initMaps(MBeanAnalyzer.java:137)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanAnalyzer.<init>(MBeanAnalyzer.java:118)
    ... 31 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.management.openmbean.OpenDataException: Cannot convert type: java.time.Duration
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.DefaultMXBeanMappingFactory.openDataException(DefaultMXBeanMappingFactory.java:1445)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.DefaultMXBeanMappingFactory.mappingForType(DefaultMXBeanMappingFactory.java:261)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.ConvertingMethod.<init>(ConvertingMethod.java:212)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.ConvertingMethod.from(ConvertingMethod.java:41)
    ... 35 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.management.openmbean.OpenDataException: Cannot convert type: java.util.List<java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit>
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.DefaultMXBeanMappingFactory.openDataException(DefaultMXBeanMappingFactory.java:1445)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.DefaultMXBeanMappingFactory.mappingForType(DefaultMXBeanMappingFactory.java:261)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.DefaultMXBeanMappingFactory.makeCompositeMapping(DefaultMXBeanMappingFactory.java:473)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.DefaultMXBeanMappingFactory.makeMapping(DefaultMXBeanMappingFactory.java:294)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.DefaultMXBeanMappingFactory.mappingForType(DefaultMXBeanMappingFactory.java:259)
    ... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.management.openmbean.OpenDataException: Cannot convert type: java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.DefaultMXBeanMappingFactory.openDataException(DefaultMXBeanMappingFactory.java:1445)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.DefaultMXBeanMappingFactory.mappingForType(DefaultMXBeanMappingFactory.java:261)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.DefaultMXBeanMappingFactory.makeArrayOrCollectionMapping(DefaultMXBeanMappingFactory.java:319)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.DefaultMXBeanMappingFactory.makeParameterizedTypeMapping(DefaultMXBeanMappingFactory.java:398)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.DefaultMXBeanMappingFactory.makeMapping(DefaultMXBeanMappingFactory.java:297)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.DefaultMXBeanMappingFactory.mappingForType(DefaultMXBeanMappingFactory.java:259)
    ... 40 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.management.openmbean.OpenDataException: Recursive data structure, including java.time.Duration
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.DefaultMXBeanMappingFactory.mappingForType(DefaultMXBeanMappingFactory.java:248)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.DefaultMXBeanMappingFactory.makeCompositeMapping(DefaultMXBeanMappingFactory.java:473)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.DefaultMXBeanMappingFactory.makeMapping(DefaultMXBeanMappingFactory.java:294)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.DefaultMXBeanMappingFactory.mappingForType(DefaultMXBeanMappingFactory.java:259)
    ... 44 common frames omitted
```

Comment: You cannot "just" upgrade 2 parts of Tomcat you will need to update everything. Assuming maven add `<tomcat.version>9.0.58</tomcat.version>` to the `<properties>` section of your `pom.xml` to properly manage the dependencies. I would also suggest not to use Tomcat DBCP but something like HikariCP for a connection pool.

Comment: Yes, I have already added `<tomcat.version>9.0.58</tomcat.version>` in pom.xml. During the build, there is a compilation error mentioned above.

Comment: I doubt it is a compilation issue. Looking at the stack trace it is devtools that tries to restart things. This is probably the culprit as you are trying to change the dependencies while the app is already running.

Comment: I had stopped the application, updated the `pom.xml`, and reloaded the maven the changes in Intellij Idea. After the changes got updated, I started the application.

Comment: What happens if you run without devtools? Please add your `pom.xml` to your question.

Comment: This is a bug, I [submitted a PR](https://github.com/apache/commons-dbcp/pull/167) to the `commons-dbcp` project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was happening when we were trying to create a BasicDataSource
`BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();` which was imported from `import org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource;`

So we found a workaround to remove the tomcat dbcp dependency by excluding it from spring-boot starter tomcat and tomcat jdbc.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-dbcp</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and Replacing the datasource to `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource dataSource = new org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource();`

Comment: You are actually ignoring the problem altogether by switching `DataSource` implementations.

Comment: Yeah, it's a workaround for now.

Comment: Are you using JMX? If not, you can temporarily disable it (cf. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28607506/11748454)). I [submitted a PR](https://github.com/apache/commons-dbcp/pull/167) for the problem you are experiencing. It might propagate to Tomcat in time for February's releases.

Comment: We are not using JMX, we can try disabling it. Thanks